# how to encode non-english web links to use in selenium

Tags: python, file-io, character-encoding, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to read some non-english (Chienese) texts from a .txt file.

```
f = open('C:\data\chinese.txt')
    for line in f:
        print line  # this displays the chinese characters properly in console
        currelem = d.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.," + line + ")]")  # this gives error as mentioned below /
```

Error Message:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector //a[contains(.,\ufeff\'\u8054\u7edc\u6211\u4eec\'\n)] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: You haven't said what tool you are using to save the files.  If you are using a program please show the method you are using.

Comment: I'm using the .txt file here. Added the details in my question as well.
Thanks.

Comment: so, the `chinese.txt` actually contains the raw html right? looks like it is one page per line.. (you might have done some pre-processing to remove the new line characters in each line, right?)

Comment: My text file doesnt contain raw html, but just the name. For example my file look like this (in Chinese),

ContactUs
LogOut
Announcement

These are the links in my webapp. 
I would want to click on these links by using, 

    d.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.," + line + ")]")

Where, when 'line' is succcessfully decoded it should be,
    d.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,"ContactUs")]")

And I have not done any pre-processing as I was not usre abt the encoding techniques. However I can see that my .txt file saved in utf-8 encoding type.

Comment: Code in my question, gives me the output for print statement correctly. But while locating the element it's not decoding it properly as the following msg explains.

//a[contains(.,\ufeff\'\u8054\u7edc\u6211\u4eec\'\n)]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual chinese.txt, I think you are missing some ' in your contains function code. Maybe it should be like:

```
f = open('C:\data\chinese.txt')
for line in f:
    print line  # this displays the chinese characters properly in console
    currelem = d.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + line + "')]")
```

Also I see \n at the end of your link and this \ufeff at the beginning. Ditch them with `line.strip()`

Comment: Still the same issue !! cannot locate the element !!

NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,\'\ufeff\u8054\u7edc\u6211\u4eec\')]"}' ;

Comment: @user159087 please post a sample of your chinese.txt in the question. I'm puzzled about this \ufeff . That should be an utf-8 sort of space, that should have been eliminated with strip().